# SEO optimized search results without JavaScript

Tags: .htaccess

I haven't found a direct answer for my question, so here it is:
I am trying to get my search results to be user and seo friendly. I believe it is a good idea to get rid of a couple of elements:

- POST search should be avoided so the browser does not bug a user to
  re-submmit the form if he goes back.
- The question mark that appends the query string
- The input name that goes with the form submmit if it is processed via an http GET (like ?**search_input**=cellphones)

So my question is a bit more: how do I turn a form submit into something like:
...mywebsite.com/search/my-search-term

...without using JavaScript to cause a redirect, but instead the form itself?
Do you guys tweak with .htaccess redirects to make your urls more "clickable", or just leave it be with the query string?

Just to be clear, the purpose of having the search user-optimized is clearly for people generating traffic through link distribution, and not to be indexed in a way or another by se's.

Thanks in advance!